# Automating TFS build definition dump process using TFPT

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to automate the TFS build definition dump process. TFPT has buildefinition /dump option which seems to be very handy. But when I execute the command, it prompts me to provide username and password to access the TFS. So I tried the following command:

> tfpt builddefinition /dump project\definition /format:detailed
>   /collection:xxx:8080/xxx /filepath:D:\log1.txt /login:Domain\id

This would fill in the username section in the credential box automatically and I would be required to fill in the password. But when I tried

> tfpt builddefinition /dump project\definition /format:detailed
>   /collection:xxx:8080/xxx /filepath:D:\log1.txt /login:Domain\id,password

I get the following error: **/Dump expects one argument but 2 were provided.**

The /login switch is not provided as an option for builddefinition. Is there a way I can automate the part where I need to give TFS username and password every time I invoke the TFPT command??

Comment: Yes, you can execute the process that tfpt under an account with TFS access. Then you won't have to specify an account as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for replying. This time I logged into TFS with the login credential and then executed the command:                           tfpt builddefinition /dump project\def /format:detailed /collection:xxx:8080/xxx /filepath:D:\log1.txt                      I get "TF30063: You are not authorized to access project" error But when I include the login information in the command I am prompted for the password and its able to dump the definition successfully. Any clue why I am facing this problem?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was executing the command in powershell. Instead if I executed the command (the one which included the login,passowrd) in VS command prompt it works perfect. Thanks again Jay!